# Custom behavior for HBase REST interface

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, cloudera

Is there a way to place my own custom jar between the REST interface and HBase to handle the XML files in a way of my choosing, query the HBase instance and return the data I want.

I need to add some business logic in and want the REST interface to take XML documents detailing my requests but in a more customer focused manner (for our particular situation), thus removing the data structure or implementation from the users eyes.

Can this be done?

Versions:

CDH 5.1.3
CM 5.1.3

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm facing a similar situation.